# How to have no underline only for specific links?

Tags: css

I have an issue that is probably very easy but I can't seem to figure it out. I got all links with no underline except on hover, active or focus:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Now, my structure in the HTML is like this:

```
<div class="filter-wrapper">
  <a href="">
      <span class="filter-tag">
        Tag Name
      </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't want any underline on hover, active or focus for that div only. How do I achieve this?

I tried doing a special class for it with text-decoration:none but it doesn't seem to work. I feel so stupid.

Comment: `.filter-wrapper a ` ??

Answer (score 3):

```
.filter-wrapper a:hover, .filter-wrapper a:focus, .filter-wrapper a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
    .filter-wrapper a:hover,
    .filter-wrapper a:focus,
    .filter-wrapper a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover,
    a:focus,
    a:active {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="filter-wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <span class="filter-tag">
        Tag Name
      </span>
  </a>
</div>

<a href="#">Test</a>
```